# Confused about Wikipedia api search freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to write the code in which one enter a word, click the button (I'll add the code later for submitting by pressing "return" button), and you get 10 results related to the word you enter. Each result will have a title/url and a description (basically, the first sentence in the page, I think?). I tried to use [API Sandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) to figure out what I need but the results I got wasn't what I was looking for. I also still don't get the difference between `list=search` and `generator=search` since they both return the results. However, it seems that I got more success when I use `list=search` when I call the title in json as **data.search[i].title** and description(?) as **data.search[i].snippet**. However, I'm unable to call the info when I use `generator=search`. The documentation for [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) was way too confusing... Basically, I wanted to call the extract of the info which seems to only happen if I use `generator=search`. However, I got an error when I tried to call the title as `data.pages[i].title` and description as `data.pages[i].extract`.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function getWord() {
  
  var keyword = $("#searchkeyword").val();
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
        prop: 'extracts',
        list: 'search',
        srsearch: keyword,
        exsentences: '1',
        exlimit: '10',
        exintro: '1',
       explaintext: '1'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        
      console.log(data);
       $("#articlearea").empty();
        
      for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          $("#articlearea").append('<div class="articlebox">' + data.query.search[i].title + '<br>' + data.query.search[i].extract + '</div>');
      }
        
        
      }
  });
};
  
    $("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord);

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiko:400,600');
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Amiko', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #40e0d0;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}
.container a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
#submitbtn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -32px;
  top: -2px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 0;
}
.fa-search {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="randomlink" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">Click here for a random Wikipedia article</a>
    <form>
      <input id="searchkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" />
      <i id="submitbtn" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </form>
    <div id="articlearea"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you display what error you're getting btw?

Comment: This is the error that I get when I use `generator=search`: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/evZzzX. I can still get the array in the console, but I also got that error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in the console too.

Comment: check out my most reason update in the code snippet below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I was asking was to access the data from `generator=search`. I forgot that I need to go inside two times for that compared to one time for `list=search`.

All I need to do is to add this code to my javascript area:

```
var pages = data.query.pages;

        for(var page in pages) {
          $("#articlearea").append('<div class="articlebox"><a target="_blank" href="' + pages[page].fullurl + '"><div class="articlelink"><h2>' + pages[page].title + '</h2>' + pages[page].extract + '</div></a></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`generator=search` won't work because that isn't an option you have the options `generator=allpages`, `generator=links`. A generator gives you either all pages of a search term or all the links. The `search` term is actually used with `gapfrom=`. Heres a working example:

```
{
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "prop": "links|categories",
    "generator": "allpages",
    "gapfrom": "Ba",
    "gaplimit": "3"
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getWord() {

    var keyword = $("#searchkeyword").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
        prop: 'info',
        generator: 'allpages',
        inprop: 'url',
        gapfrom: keyword,
        gaplimit: "3"
      },
      success: function(data) {

        var pages = Object.keys(data.query.pages);
        
        $("#articlearea").empty();
        
        pages.forEach(page => {
          $("#articlearea").append('<div class="articlebox">' + JSON.stringify(data.query.pages[page].title) + '<br>' + JSON.stringify(data.query.pages[page].canonicalurl) + '</div>');
        })


      }
    });
  };

  $("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord);

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiko:400,600');
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Amiko', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #40e0d0;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.container a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#submitbtn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -32px;
  top: -2px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 0;
}

.fa-search {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="randomlink" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">Click here for a random Wikipedia article</a>
    <form>
      <input id="searchkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" />
      <button id="submitbtn" class="fa fa-search"></button>
    </form>
    <div id="articlearea"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the form to add a "on submit" to automatically run your getWords() function.  I also changed the action to javascript:void() to avoid a refresh.  I also changed your getWord() and took it out of the document.ready function because it's not accessible form the form "onsubmit" as it was.   Now, the code should be functioning.  If you need any more help, just comment.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<a id="randomlink" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">Click here for a random Wikipedia article</a>
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="getWord()">
  <input id="searchkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" />
  <i id="submitbtn" class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>
<div id="articlearea"></div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getWord() {

var keyword = $("#searchkeyword").val();

$.ajax({
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    action: 'query',
    format: 'json',
    prop: 'extracts',
    list: 'search',
    srsearch: keyword,
    exsentences: '1',
    exlimit: '10',
    exintro: '1',
      explaintext: '1'
  },
  success: function(data) {

  console.log(data);
   $("#articlearea").empty();

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $("#articlearea").append('<div class="articlebox">' + data.query.search[i].title +  '</div>');
  }


  }
});
};

$("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord);

</script>
```